# How to correctly handle the case where a stream is empty

Tags: spring-webflux

How do I perform operations that have side effects in response to a stream being empty? For example, to handle the case where a client sends an empty body, and we read it with `.bodyToMono(...)`.

See for example:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createEventDetails(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.principal().flatMap(principal -> {
        UserProfile userProfile = (UserProfile) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getCredentials();

        final String id = request.pathVariable("id");
        final UUID eventId = UUID.fromString(id);

        return request.bodyToMono(CreateEventDetailsRequest.class)
            .map(body -> new CreateEventDetailsCommand(eventId, userProfile, body.getObjectId(), body.getDocumentUrls()))
            .flatMap(command -> {
                createEventDetailsCommandHandler.handle(command);
                return ServerResponse
                    .created(URI.create(eventId.toString()))
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(new CreateEventDetailsResponse(eventId)));
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest().syncBody(new Error("missing request body for event id: " + id)))
            .map(response -> {
                LOG.error("POST createEventDetails: missing request body for event id: " + id);
                return response;
            });
    });
}
```

This returns the desired 400 response in the case that the client omits the request body, but the log message is always printed, even for successful requests.

My best guess as to why this occurs, is that `.switchIfEmpty(...).map(...)` is executed as one unit by the framework, and then the result ignored.

How do I handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. In the case above you can just add the logging to the switch
e.g.

```
.switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest().syncBody(new Error("missing request body for event id: " + id))
       .doOnNext(errorResponse -> LOG.error("POST createEventDetails: missing request body for event id: " + id)
)
```

another approach could be sending an Error signal back and in your handler catch and log it.
You can have a look here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors
Some light reading can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebHandler.html

> Use HttpWebHandlerAdapter to adapt a WebHandler to an HttpHandler. The
>   WebHttpHandlerBuilder provides a convenient way to do that while also
>   optionally configuring one or more filters and/or exception handlers.

You can view a sample handler in `ResponseStatusExceptionHandler`